# Match two XML with PowerShell and result a subtracted third XML?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I want to match with powershell script supplierproductcode from File 1 against File 2. When it finds a match it should create a third file with the same informaton but subtract quantity in File 1 from File 2.

File 1

```
<stocklevelrecord>
    <supplierproductcode>1111</supplierproductcode>
    <quantity>100</quantity>
</stocklevelrecord>
<stocklevelrecord>
    <supplierproductcode>3333</supplierproductcode>
    <quantity>100</quantity>
</stocklevelrecord>
```

File 2

```
<stocklevelrecord>
    <supplierproductcode>1111</supplierproductcode>
    <quantity>20</quantity>
</stocklevelrecord>
<stocklevelrecord>
    <supplierproductcode>2222</supplierproductcode>
    <quantity>30</quantity>
</stocklevelrecord>
<stocklevelrecord>
    <supplierproductcode>3333</supplierproductcode>
    <quantity>40</quantity>
</stocklevelrecord>
<stocklevelrecord>
    <supplierproductcode>4444</supplierproductcode>
    <quantity>50</quantity>
</stocklevelrecord>
```

The result file

```
# quantity 100 (File 1) - quantity 20 (File 2)
<stocklevelrecord>
    <supplierproductcode>1111</supplierproductcode>
    <quantity>80</quantity>
</stocklevelrecord>
# quantity 100 (File 1) - quantity 40 (File 2)
<stocklevelrecord>
    <supplierproductcode>3333</supplierproductcode>
    <quantity>60</quantity>
</stocklevelrecord>
```

I am completely new to PowerShell and need guidance.

Comment: There's not a straightforward answer to this (diff'ing hierarchical data structures is _hard_), I'd suggest you find a nice diff-tool and invoke that from PowerShell rather than attempting to implement this yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach would be to iterate over the records in the first file, look up the codes in the second file, and update the quantity.

Note that this works best for small files. Larger files (hundreds of KB or MB) might benefit from indexing such as a dictionary to avoid loading the entire document into memory.

```powershell
function Format-XML ([xml]$xml, $indent=2)
{
    # https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/format-xml/
    $StringWriter = New-Object System.IO.StringWriter
    $XmlWriter = New-Object System.XMl.XmlTextWriter $StringWriter
    $xmlWriter.Formatting = “indented”
    $xmlWriter.Indentation = $Indent
    $xml.WriteContentTo($XmlWriter)
    $XmlWriter.Flush()
    $StringWriter.Flush()
    Write-Output $StringWriter.ToString()
}

[xml] $file1 = "
<records>
    <stocklevelrecord>
        <supplierproductcode>1111</supplierproductcode>
        <quantity>100</quantity>
    </stocklevelrecord>
    <stocklevelrecord>
        <supplierproductcode>3333</supplierproductcode>
        <quantity>100</quantity>
    </stocklevelrecord>
</records>"

[xml] $file2 = "
<records>
    <stocklevelrecord>
        <supplierproductcode>1111</supplierproductcode>
        <quantity>20</quantity>
    </stocklevelrecord>
    <stocklevelrecord>
        <supplierproductcode>2222</supplierproductcode>
        <quantity>30</quantity>
    </stocklevelrecord>
    <stocklevelrecord>
        <supplierproductcode>3333</supplierproductcode>
        <quantity>40</quantity>
    </stocklevelrecord>
    <stocklevelrecord>
        <supplierproductcode>4444</supplierproductcode>
        <quantity>50</quantity>
    </stocklevelrecord>
</records>"

foreach ($file1Record in $file1.records.stocklevelrecord)
{
    $file1Code = $file1Record.supplierproductcode
    $file1Quantity = $file1Record.quantity

    foreach ($file2Record in $file2.records.stocklevelrecord)
    {
        $file2Code = $file2Record.supplierproductcode
        $file2Quantity = $file2Record.quantity

        if ($file1Code -eq $file2Code)
        {
            $file1Record.quantity = ($file1Quantity - $file2Quantity).ToString()
        }
    }
}

Clear-Host
Format-Xml $file1

# Output
#
# <records>
#   <stocklevelrecord>
#     <supplierproductcode>1111</supplierproductcode>
#     <quantity>80</quantity>
#   </stocklevelrecord>
#   <stocklevelrecord>
#     <supplierproductcode>3333</supplierproductcode>
#     <quantity>60</quantity>
#   </stocklevelrecord>
# </records>
```